# Vector of functions in APL

Tags: arrays, function, functional-programming, apl, dyalog

What is the syntax for a vector (array) of functions in APL?

I have tried the following but these are interpreted as a 3-train and a 2-train, respectively:

```
{1},{2}
```

```
{1} {2}
```

PS. I am looking to do this with more complex (and possibly named) functions by the way, the `{1}` above is just so the *example is short*.

Comment: APL is not as _functional_ as you might think. A function cannot directly be an entry in a vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays of functions can be obtained using `⎕OR` ([Object Representation](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/System%20Functions/or.htm)) and the fact that such objects implicitly become reconstituted into functions when used as operands. (You can also do it explicitly using `⎕FX`.) It is easiest to define some helper operators first:

```
      _Arrayify←{f←⍺⍺ ⋄ ⎕OR'f'}
      _Apply←{2=⎕NC'⍺':⍺ ⍺⍺ ⍵ ⋄ ⍺⍺ ⍵}
```

Now, let's define some sample functions:

```
      A←{2×⍵}
      B←{⍵÷2}
      C←{-⍵}
```

We create a 3-element vector of functions, and check that it is indeed a "normal" array:

```
      fnArray←(A _Arrayify⍬)(B _Arrayify⍬)(C _Arrayify⍬)
      ⍴fnArray
3
```

Let's extract the second function and apply it:

```
      (2⊃fnArray)_Apply 10
5
```

We can also create an application *function*, so we can use operators on it:

```
      Apply←{⍺ _Apply ⍵}
      fnArray Apply¨10
20 5 ¯10
```

Answer (score 5):

Dyalog APL does not officially support function arrays, you can awkwardly emulate them by creating an array of namespaces with identically named functions.

```
      (a←⎕NS⍬).f←2∘×
      (b←⎕NS⍬).f←÷∘2
      (c←⎕NS⍬).f←-
      f←(a b c).f
      f 4
8 2 ¯4
```

[Maria Wells suggested an operator to produce an array of functions](https://dfns.dyalog.com/n_fnarray.htm)

Comment: Problem is that you can't index into the array of functions to select which one to apply, so it is really no different than `f←(⊂2∘×),(⊂÷∘2),(⊂-)`

Comment: But if you leave the functions in the namespaces, you have an array ( albeit of namespaces and not actual functions) and you can index into it and manipulate like any other array. This is what happens as a matter of course when calling a method on an array of objects, a very powerful feature of Dyalog.

Comment: Encapsulating a function in a namespace and taking the object representation are both kluges to implement function arrays and its not clear to me the latter is more elegant or powerful than the former.

Comment: Is one more portable than the other (`⎕or` and `⎕nc` vs `⎕ns`)? I have read somewhere that namespaces were ISO standard APL but can't find a mention of them in the actual standard.